# apt-get not found on my VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, apt, ubuntu-12.04

Today, I bought a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS from http://www.frontrangehosting.com, but when I access it via SSH, I can't use apt-get.

```
[root@vps /]# apt-get install python-software-properties
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

edit: For some reason, it can't find lsb-release

```
[root@vps /]# cat /etc/lsb-release
cat: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you ***sure*** you chose Ubuntu? just for fun: try `yum search python` to see if yum is installed.

Comment: And even if you chose Ubuntu, a different system may have been provisioned (default seems to be CentOS). Type `cat /etc/lsb-release` to check out.

Comment: @petrus I already tried that.

[root@vps /]# cat /etc/lsb-release
cat: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the contents of `/boot`?

Comment: @Zoredache [root@vps boot]# ls  ->  grub

Comment: `lsb-release` doesn't exist on several of my systems, though others do. Try `cat /etc/*-release`.

Comment: @tehtros: lsb-release is present on ubuntu systems. If you don't have it, then it's not a ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you @Micha you really helped! It turns out, they installed CentOS 6.2 instead. Thank you!

Comment: @tehtros As I suspected. I've made a full answer out of it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your shell prompt, it appears you have CentOS or some other Red Hat-derived distribution rather than the Ubuntu you were expecting.

You can confirm this by running:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

and inspecting the output.

Answer (score 2):

When you login you should run :

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Does that show the operating system?  If not I'd drop a mail to your providers support address - it is possible they just gave you the wrong distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to run the command lsb_release, because that is the one that is defined in the standard, not where its information is saved.

"lsb_release -a" should give you more information than you ever wanted about your system. On my dedicated server I get this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

I've use that command both on Ubuntu (version 8.04 through 12.04) and Redhat ES/AS 4-6.